# AWS Sticky session cookie not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, cookies, amazon-alb

I'm using an application load balancer with the target group of two instances. In the target group, I have enabled application based cookie. However whenever I test the load balancer, it keeps switching to both instances. (I have put IP address on each instance, so I can see that it's going to both instances). Shouldn't it go to the same instance every time? How can I fix that?

[Here's how I have set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2olo.jpg)

[Here's what I see in the target group attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnViO.jpg)

[Cookies in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzAFW.jpg)

Comment: Do you see `MYCUSTOMAPPCOOKIE` being set in the browser?

Comment: @ceejayoz I added screenshots, please check.